# Move IP configuration from one interface to another

Tags: python, linux, networking

I am developing a Python script that tests one networking application. As part of the test, it needs to move networking configuration (IP address, routes ...) from one interface (*physical interface*) to another interface (*bridge*), and after the test is done, restore the system back to its original state. What is the most elegant approach to accomplish this in Python?

Some ideas I have thought about:

1. To not unassign the IP address from *physical interface* during the test, so that routes are not lost. But this would mean that the same IP address would coexist on the *bridge* during the test. Would this be a problem on some particular Linux Kernels? Although, it seems to work just fine on my system...
2. Assign the IP address to *bridge* and unassign from *physical interface*. Easy to implement in python, because this requires to do simple `ifconfig` calls and parsing. But if the default route was through the *physical interface*, then it would disappear at the same time, when I unassigned the IP address from *physical interface*.
3. Parse the `ip route ls` output and move the routes together with the IP config. This seems the only reasonable approach, but would require quite a lot of coding.
4. Maybe there is something more elegant? Like `iptables-save eth0>eth0_conf`, `iptables-restore eth0_conf`? Any other suggestions?

This test tool must be portable, and be able to run on different Linux Kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Ensure the bridge interface is down
2. Configure the bridge interface
3. Execute `ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig br0 up`

And to restore:

1. Execute `ifconfig br0 down && ifconfig eth0 up`

Now for the routes it depends on what kind of routes you have. If you defined static routes with explicit interfaces, your only choice seems to be parsing `ip route ls` and translating them to the new interface.

You can also toy around with the order of the up & down commands as well as multiple routing tables:

```
ip route add <whatever> table 2
ip rule add from br0 table 2
```

But this can get tricky, so my suggestion would be to stick to the simple solution, even if it includes some more coding.

Here is another example from xend's `network-bridge` script to achieve this:

```
# Usage: transfer_addrs src dst
# Copy all IP addresses (including aliases) from device $src to device $dst.
transfer_addrs () {
    local src=$1
    local dst=$2
    # Don't bother if $dst already has IP addresses.
    if ip addr show dev ${dst} | egrep -q '^ *inet ' ; then
        return
    fi
    # Address lines start with 'inet' and have the device in them.
    # Replace 'inet' with 'ip addr add' and change the device name $src
    # to 'dev $src'.
    ip addr show dev ${src} | egrep '^ *inet ' | sed -e "
s/inet/ip addr add/
s@\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+\)@\1@
s/${src}/dev ${dst}/
" | sh -e
    # Remove automatic routes on destination device
    ip route list | sed -ne "
/dev ${dst}\( \|$\)/ {
  s/^/ip route del /
  p
}" | sh -e
}

# Usage: transfer_routes src dst
# Get all IP routes to device $src, delete them, and
# add the same routes to device $dst.
# The original routes have to be deleted, otherwise adding them
# for $dst fails (duplicate routes).
transfer_routes () {
    local src=$1
    local dst=$2
    # List all routes and grep the ones with $src in.
    # Stick 'ip route del' on the front to delete.
    # Change $src to $dst and use 'ip route add' to add.
    ip route list | sed -ne "
/dev ${src}\( \|$\)/ {
  h
  s/^/ip route del /
  P
  g
  s/${src}/${dst}/
  s/^/ip route add /
  P
  d
}" | sh -e
}
```

Comment: I like your approach of bringing up/down the interface to restore routes. I guess that this might might work for me. Now the only problem is - How to move the routes from eth0->br0 (I believe both interfaces should be up during the test).

Comment: @AnsisAtteka can you elaborate a bit more on your setup? What interfaces does br0 contain? Are eth0 and br0 on the same physical network? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Having two physical interfaces in the same subnet can be a pain, at least in my experience. I managed to get around them by using seperate routing tables for the interfaces

Comment: br0 is bridge (Software Defined Switch) where I virtually plug in the eth0 interface (e.g. "ovs-vsctl add-port bre0 eth0" or "brctl addif br0 eth0" commands).

Comment: Also I see some potential problems with DHCP, if I would bring down/up the interface to restore the ip+route configuration. Although I do not expect to encounter them in real world, because I believe that in most setups the DHCP server would assign the same IP address after I bring the interface up again.

Comment: @AnsisAtteka Have you looked at how xen does this? They have exactly the same use-case in their network-bridge script (not vif-bridge, that only adds VM interfaces to the bridge). Google should be able to point you in the right direction, otherwise I can get it from one of my xenhosts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10190/discussion-between-ansis-atteka-and-mensi)

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in transfer_routes() implementation. This function incorrectly assumes that "ip route show" will print routes in the correct dependency order. For example, If I would try to move the default route before the local subnet route, then this function would fail. By the way, starting with Ubuntu 12.04 (Linux 3.2) I have noticed that routes are printed in reverse order with ip command.